# SQL which removes entries with duplicate emails

Tags: mysql, delete

```
DELETE
FROM Person
WHERE Id IN (
 SELECT Id
 FROM Person
 GROUP BY Email
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND Id <> MIN(Id)
)
```

The above query produces the error:

```
You can't specify target table 'Person' for update in FROM clause
```

Why?

I am just trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/) problem to improve my SQL skills.

I checked the above SQL query [here](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) and it seems my syntax is fine.

Comment: Specify definite DBMS. MySQL, error 1093?

Comment: @Akina, yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple-table [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) syntax:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM Person t1
JOIN Person t2 USING (Email)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```